# CustomScrollView gives "Vertical viewport was given unbounded height." error

Tags: flutter, user-interface, mobile

First of all I know there is lots of question like that but I tried many things but none of them worked. I just want my column and futurebuilder widget to be scrollable together.

I have two widgets and a row in a column widget.
My first widget is a Column named "_mainPost":

```
Widget _mainPost(...) {
    return Column(
        children: [
            ...
        ],
    ),
  }
```

and second widget is a futurebuilder named "commentFeed":

```
Widget _commentFeed(){
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: comments,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text("Error"),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List<CommentElement> comments = snapshot.data;
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: comments.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                CommentElement thisItem = comments[index];
                return _commentLayout(context, thisItem);
              });
        }
        return Center(
          child: Image.asset("assets/gifs/loading_block.gif"),
        );
      },
    );
}
```

And I put them together like that:

```
SafeArea(
  child: Container(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          //...
        ),
        //both _mainPostLayout and _commentFeed must be scrollable together.
        Expanded(
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: _mainPost(
                    //some input
                ),
              ),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: _commentFeed(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

What i'm trying to do is that these two widgets can be scrolled together.
I tried changing `Expanded()` Widget to a container with a height value `container(height: 500)`. But nothing changed.
I tried putting them on `SingleChildScrollView` and giving it `shrinkwrap:true` doesn't changed anyting.
I tried using CustomScrollView and slivers but same.
The output I expect from my code is:

[image: From]
[image: To]

instead I get unbounded height error everytime I try something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the parent CustomScrollView is handling scrolling, you don't need to add ListView, You can use `Column` widget.

```dart
if (snapshot.hasData) {
  List<CommentElement> comments = snapshot.data;
  return Column(
    children: comments.map((e) {
      return _commentLayout(context, e);
    }).toList(),
  );
}
```

This should also work

```dart
if (snapshot.hasData) {
  return Column(
    children: snapshot.data.map((e) => _commentLayout(context, e)),
  ).toList();
}
```

But while we are inside Sliver, I think using SliverList is more suitable.

```dart
Widget _commentFeed() { // dont need to wrap with SliverToBoxAdapter on CustomScrollView
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: comments,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return const SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Center(
            child: Text("Error"),
          ),
        );
      }
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        List<CommentElement> comments = snapshot.data;
        return SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
            return _commentLayout(context, comments[index]);
          }
          childCount: comments.length,),
        );
      }
      return SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Image.asset("assets/gifs/loading_block.gif"),
      );
    },
  );
}
```